# Cannot access configuration pages

Tags: 7

Dead configuration link

Hi, I am developing a Drupal 7 website with MAMP and everything works ok, except that when I access on some configuration pages, all that appears is a non themed breadcrumd and the page title on a white background. The Database was migrated from a Windows 7 WAMP install, and the pages display correctly on that machine.

Comment: Clear cache and check again.

Comment: Thanks but that does not work, seems to be some kind of database problem